# Passing data to react-native from native with proguard

Tags: react-native, obfuscation, android-proguard

Without proguard=true following is WritableMap which is passed to React native.

```
{isDone:true}
```

And I enable obfuscation

```
{a:true}
```

I want pro guard not to touch this class. What to add in proguard file?

Answer (score 0):

Add following to proguard-rules.pro:

```
-keep, includedescriptorclasses public class packagename.model.** {*; }
```